# Search URL parameters query

Tags: customization, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom search form with empty parameters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67790/custom-search-form-with-empty-parameters)

Hopefully this is a quick one, but I've hit a wall here.

I have multiple search terms, keyword, category, country and date. I've set it up so that the user doesn't have to search all of these filters. I can leave off category and/or date and it will show looser results.

But if I leave off country it shows no results, doing the same to any other parameter still shows results. The problem lies with country only.

`/?s=a&cat=41&country=&monthnum=&year=` produces no results but

`/?s=a&cat=41&monthnum=&year=` does.

Why is this? Surely these are the same thing?

This is my wp_query, simply pulls posts, I had the foreach to clear this issue before but currently if I remove it. The search works no differently.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post')
// This foreach doesn't actually need to be here ?
foreach(array('s', 'cat', 'country', 'monthnum', 'year') as $key) {
    if(isset($_GET[$key]) && trim($_GET[$key]) !== '') {
        $args[$key] = $_GET[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: My best guess is that country is a reserved parameter in wordpress. Changing "country" to something like "abc_country" might get it to work.

Comment: A fair guess but it is not

Comment: Answer found on a separate <A href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67790/custom-search-form-with-empty-parameters">post</a>:

Answer (score 2):

Your query variable `country` is not defined, its not part of the standard `query_vars` set by WordPress, where as both `monthnum` and `year` are and that's why they work and the former does not.

So you need to add your query variable into the mix, try the following;

```
function new_query_var() {

    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('country');

}

add_filter('init', 'new_query_var');
```

Also, it appears that your `foreach` is checking for the existing of this query variable and hence since its not set (e.g. `isset`) then it fails the conditional check.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. And yes, that makes sense about the foreach. I added your function into functions.php but still no change. It refused to find anything if the `country=` is present. Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: Replace the `if { }` block temporarily with `var_dump($key);` what do you see?

Comment: I got this `string(1) "s" string(3) "cat" string(7) "country" string(8) "monthnum" string(4) "year"` from these url parameters `/?s=a&cat=41&country=&monthnum=10&year=2012`